# How to add Java EE SDK libraries in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I have installed the Java EE SDK on my Windows machine and I got a glassfish3 folder. Which files, and how do I add the libraries needed in IntelliJ? And is the servlet api included in the sdk?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are going to develop. Normally IDEA needs just **Java SE** SDK and when you need **Java EE** features, you specify an application server in `Settings` | `Application Servers`.

Application server libraries include servlet and many other Java EE APIs. In IntelliJ IDEA module settings application server is [added as a dependency](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) so that all the APIs will be available for code completion, running and debugging.

Check out [Tomcat and other tutorials](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/) if you are just starting.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project and once a basic setup with Java EE support is created, hit **F4** on the module. This will open up the module settings (you can also right click on a module and open the **Module Settings** item).

This is your one stop entry for all things settings. You can add a library, module library, global SDK etc from here.

Generally, when you create a library, you can specify all the directories under which you have your jars.

*For example*: In your case, you might need to add *servlet.jar* in the project path. Just add a library with the Jar directory path in which the servlet jar exists.